# Why is 不 sometimes put between the syllables of a 2-syllable word?

Tags: grammar

For example,

> 看见 - 看**不**见
>
> 离开 - 离**不**开

but

> 喜欢 - **不**喜欢
>
> 知道 - **不**知道

Why is this done and how do I know if I should or shouldn't do it when negating? Couldn't find anything on the Internet.

Comment: A resource to expand on Tang Ho's answer: https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Potential_complement

Comment: does ＂finer points of the Chinese language＂include basic grammar?

Answer (score 3):

There are only two potential particles, and they are 得 and 不

When a potential particle is inserted between a verb and its result complement, it turn that verb from an active verb into a potential verb

Examples:

> 看見 = See
>
> 看得見 = can see
>
> 看不見 = can’t see

~

> 聽到 = hear
>
> 聽得到 = can hear
>
> 聽不到 = can‘t hear

When an adverb 不 or 沒 is placed before a verb, it funcutions as  ‘not’ and ‘have not’ respectively.

Examples:

> 看 = to see
>
> 不看 = not to see

~

> 有看 = have seen
>
> 沒看 = have not seen